# Why does this WebStorm configuration not allow me to hit breakpoints in my node application?

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm, grafana, run-configuration

I'm trying to debug an application that has a go backend and a node.js front-end. I run the backend with just a simple `bra run`, which emits:

`NFO[12-08|11:57:59] Initializing HTTP Server    logger=http.server address=0.0.0.0:3000 protocol=http subUrl= socket=`

I then try to run a debugging session in WebStorm, with the following **npm** configuration:

[image]

This outputs the following when I start the debugging session:

```
/usr/local/bin/node --inspect-brk /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run watch --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

To debug the "watch" script, make sure the $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION string is specified as the first argument for the node command you'd like to debug.
For example:
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js"
  }
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/7c6f9f1b-377e-4a07-b7f8-0155b0d59adb
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
```

So I'm pretty new to debugging web apps in general, but I expected that I could now just open my browser to `localhost:3000/my/script.js` and have breakpoints in WebStorm get hit. This isn't the case though; I can navigate my application just fine (even with just the `bra run` command and the debugging session not active in WebStorm), but it doesn't trigger any breakpoints in WebStorm. I'm also not entirely sure what the `ws://128.0.0.1:9229` endpoint is for, but I assume it has something to do with why I can't get anything to work.

I've been struggling with this for hours and am pretty stuck on how to get the application to run so that I can use WebStorm to debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this configuration, you are debugging the `watch` npm script, not the application served by grafana. To debug the application, you should have created a **JavaScript debug** run configuration, specifying `localhost:3000` as URL.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html, **Debugging an application running on an external web server**

Comment: Thanks, I've done this and can now see console.log() output in webstorm, however not a single breakpoint is hit. I think this is a separate question though.

Comment: submitted related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720665/breakpoints-in-webstorm-not-hitting-for-javascript-debugging