# Breakpoints in WebStorm not hitting for JavaScript debugging

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, remote-debugging, run-configuration

I have the following configuration setup in WebStorm:

[image]

When I click debug, it launches Chrome fine and navigates to the page, but my breakpoints never get hit. It's connected somehow though because I see all of the `console.log()` output in WebStorm.

I'm trying to navigate to the URL specified in the screenshot and have breakpoints in `main.js` get hit, but it doesn't work as expected (see: at all). I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing. I've tried setting a remote URL for the specific `main.js` file in the *Remote URLs* section, but that didn't help either.

For reference I run the application via `bra run` and `npm run watch`.

**Quick Update**

So I've been able to actually get a breakpoint to hit, but it's in a different file (in a different path):

`../public/app/core/routes/dashboard_loaders.ts` allows me to stop at breakpoints, but `../public/dashboards` doesn't.

[image]

When I navigate to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/script/main.js?orgId=1, it hits the route:

```
.when('/dashboard/:type/:slug', {
    templateUrl: 'public/app/partials/dashboard.html',
    controller : 'LoadDashboardCtrl',
    reloadOnSearch: false,
    pageClass: 'page-dashboard',
  })
```

Which ultimately *does* load the file `../public/dashboards/multi.js` -- but no breakpoints are hit.

**Further Updates**

It looks like the script is served via [the following command](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/public/app/features/dashboard/dashboardLoaderSrv.js#L84) (in `../public/app/features/dashboard/dashboardLoaderSrv.js`):

```
/*jshint -W054 */
var script_func = new Function('ARGS','kbn','dateMath','_','moment','window','document','$','jQuery', 'services', result.data);
var script_result = script_func($routeParams, kbn, dateMath, _ , moment, window, document, $, $, services);
```

Where `$routeParams` are `type:script` and `slug:main.js` - If I step into this function, I get an anonymous(?) file that's identical to my actual `main.js` file, but the name is like `43550` instead of `main.js` -- I think this is boiling down to a fundamental lack of knowledge in how JavaScript handles something on my part. :)

Comment: Does your browser have the IntelliJ debug plugin (and is it present as a yellow banner on top when you try to debug from the IDE)?

Comment: I do, it only shows up when I right-click and select `Inspect in WebStorm` -- it reloads the page, but breakpoints still don't get hit (and console logging in WebStorm stops)

Comment: I do not really know the source for your issue, but as a workaround you could use the Chrome debugger and write "debugger;" in your Javascript-Code and Chrome will break at this point if the development tools are open. I like it more than the WebStorm-debugger as it uses [proper colorization for warnings and errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330022/webstorm-debugging-with-chrome-best-workflow-with-useful-console-and-setting-b).

Comment: The issue with this hack is it forces me to type "debugger" everywhere I want to stop, and also requires that I remember to go back and delete every single `debugger` command in the source before committing.

Comment: You can also set breakpoints in the Chrome debugger by opening the Sources panel and clicking in the left margin. No `debugger;` statement needed.

Comment: I tried running this grafana thingy locally and I can't get it to work. Ugh. Have you tried running the frontend app via command line and then attaching to it with the "attach to node.js/chrome" configuration?

Comment: @MichaelGeary You can't it is dynamically loaded

Comment: @MrDuk Updated answer 2 time, If there was a reason why the sourceURL thing didn't work in your past ticket let me know.

Comment: The same problem in IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.3.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I found this [issue for using webstorm with grafana](https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-debug-in-webstorm/4203/9) (second edit) looks like this is you.
I think what he linked solves it with declaring a sourceUrl then your file isn't "anonymous" or rather dynamic.

```
//# sourceURL=filename.js
```

I.E

```
//# sourceURL=main.js
```

Reference [How to debug dynamically loaded JavaScript (with jQuery) in the browser's debugger itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092125/how-to-debug-dynamically-loaded-javascript-with-jquery-in-the-browsers-debugg/9092205#9092205)

---

Here is the documentation and video on debugging in webstorm to make sure everything is setup properly. (I.E My default setting were to debug my index file instead of my project). Make sure you have their [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji?hl=en) or [Firefox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jetbrains-toolbox/)

[General JS Debugging in Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/javascript.html#ws_js_debugging_overview)

[Debugging for Chrome in Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html)

[Debugging for Firefox in Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/debugging-javascript-in-firefox.html)

[Debugging Node.JS in Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html)

Comment: Updated after looking through git issues